# C++ throw an exception in a function and catch it in the caller?

Tags: c++, exception

I have a function that returns a 'vector'. However, sometimes during runtime the function can encounter an error in which it should not return the vector but instead return a value that can be checked by caller. Should I handle this by throwing an exception and catching it in the caller or should I change the return type of the function to 'std::pair' that stores a return value (0 or 1) and the vector. I don't want to exit the program with 'std::runtime 'error if the conditions occurs.

```
std::vector<int> function() {

std::vector ans;
//do stuff

if (something happens)
    return -1;

return ans;

}
```

Comment: `std::optional` seems more appropriate than `std::pair`. Else both approaches are valid.

Comment: Is "something happens" something *exceptional*? This is more of a design issue than a code issue.

Comment: Doesn't sound like encountering the error is exceptional; sounds routine and expected.  I've seen the pattern `bool TryFunction(std::vector<int>& output)` that indicates if setting `output` parameter was successful (true), or unsuccessful (false).  That's more of a C#-ism, but I've seen it sometimes used in C++ as well.  I'd use `std::variant`, but some people don't like the callsite having to unpackage the variant object.

Comment: `I don't want to exit the program with 'std::runtime 'error if the conditions occurs` Exceptions were designed so that if there is an error that is not handled the application shuts down. This is fantastic and stops so many problems. If you fail to handle an error returned by a function this is usually a sever problem in your code and finding the issue becomes really hard. Throwing an exception when there is a problem forces you to explicitly handle that problem to keep the program running correctly so it seems like a good use case in this circumstance.

Comment: @Eljay Personally I think theological debates over the strictest meaning of the term "exceptional" are wildly overused. The function's purpose is to return a value, and if one is not available then an exception is appropriate. That's what they're for. Exceptions aren't just for things you "never expect to happen"; look at `std::vector::at` - you could get a 100% exception throwing rate if you just pass the right (wrong?!) argument. It's totally routine but also perfectly fine.

Comment: Note: I agree with @Eljay mostly. I am just not convinced this is "Routine control flow" to me this sounds like an exception. But there is very little context here to know for sure.

Comment: People get their code all in a twizzle trying to arm wrestle themselves into complex error-handling machinery for no reason.

Comment: @MartinYork • Yep, that's the crux for me.  Insufficient context, so the advice is heavily qualified.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I hate the term: `"something happens" something exceptional`. What does exceptional even  mean! I think the better definition is whether the error can be handled by the local context (can it be handled in the method/class). If it can be handled locally then return an error code otherwise throw an exception. Error codes are great locally but allowing them to cross an interface boundary is asking for trouble (as there is no forced check on the result).

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a good time for an exception. Make a throwable type that can have a constructor argument, some sort of code that explains the problem. The catcher can check that code.

People will suggest `std::variant` and such instead, but that gets messy quite quickly and causes your function's signature to balloon. It also complicates the code at the callsite. There's no need for it here. Exceptions were literally designed for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

My first choice would be a `std::variant` (it is better then `std::optional` since it can provide extra information in case of error and this is always beneficial in the future):

```
usign ErrorType = int;
using ReturnType = std::variant<std::vector<int>, ErrorType>

ReturnType function() {

    std::vector ans;
    //do stuff

    if (something happens)
        return -1;

    return ans;
}
```

If your error is quite rare and exception could be cough in deeper caller level then exception is also a good/better way:

```
class MyException : public std::exception {
public:
    MyException(int errorCode) : exception("MyException"), errorCode(errorCode)
    {}

    int code() const { return errorCode; }
private:
    int errorCode;
};

std::vector<int> function() {

    std::vector ans;
    //do stuff

    if (something happens)
        throw MyException{ -1 };

    return ans;
}
```

Please remember that in C++ exceptions are design in such way that they are zero cost when nothing is thrown. Trade of is that when something exception is thrown unwinding a stack is extremely slow (on some cpp-con someone said that it is x40 slower, I didn't measure it). This is the reason use of `std::optional` or `std::variant` instead of exception can be so beneficial.

AFAIK standard comity is working on [new kind of exceptions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0709r0.pdf) mechanism which will behave like `std::variant` (similar how this is made in Swift).

Answer (score -2):

You can use `std::optional` for it.

Comment: While this may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Comment: if OP didnt know how to use `std::optional` they will also not know after reading this answer...